# Can anyone tell me how to add post editor in widget sidebar in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a sidebar Widget in WordPress admin with the editor and title like how we simple create pages and post but without plugin.

Comment: Your question is not clear to what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @EniGma  i want to make sidebar in wordpress where user can add content in same way like title and below that editor basically i need editor in my sidebar to add and delete its content

Comment: According to what you said, What I can recommend is `Custom Field Widget Plugin` you can find it in this link `https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-widget/`.

Comment: I am attaching a screenshot please have a look at it   http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2133337/d194be83d84fda2e63338c069e2ce712 this is how i want it with some custom code

Comment: See This Link, It may help you `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82670/why-cant-wp-editor-be-used-in-a-custom-widget`